# How to map a RDD of type org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]]?

Tags: scala, mapreduce, apache-spark

I am new to Spark and Scala.
I have an RDD that is of type `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]]`.

Here is a listing from `myRdd.take(3)`.

```
Array(Array(1, 2524474, CBSGPRS, 1, 2015-09-09 10:42:03, 0, 47880, 302001131103734, NAT, "", 502161081073570, "", BLANK, UNK, "", "", "", MV_PVC, BLANK, 1, "", 0, 475078439, 41131;0;0, "", 102651;0;0, 3|3), Array(2, 2524516, CBSGPRS, 1, 2015-09-09 23:42:14, 0, 1260, 302001131104272, NAT, "", 502161081074085, "", BLANK, UNK, "", "", "", MV_PVC, BLANK, 1, "", 0, 2044745984, 3652;0;0, "", 8636;0;0, 3|3), Array(3, 2524545, CBSGPRS, 1, 2015-09-09 14:56:55, 0, 32886, 302001131101629, NAT, "", 502161081071599, "", BLANK, UNK, "", "", "", MV_PVC, BLANK, 1, "", 0, 1956194307, 14164657;0;0, "", 18231194;0;0, 3|3))
```

I am trying to map it as follows ..

```
var gprsMap = frows.collect().map{ tuple =>
// bind variables to the tuple
var (recKey, origRecKey, recTypeId, durSpanId, timestamp, prevConvDur, convDur,
    msisdn, callType, aPtyCellId, aPtyImsi, aPtyMsrn, bPtyNbr, bPtyNbrTypeId,
    bPtyCellId, bPtyImsi, bPtyMsrn, inTrgId, outTrgId, callStatusId, suppSvcId, provChgAmt,
    genFld1, genFld2, genFld3, genFld4, genFld5) = tuple

var dtm = timestamp.split(" ");
var idx = timestamp indexOf ' '
var dt = timestamp slice(0, idx)
var tm = timestamp slice(idx + 1, timestamp.length)

// return the results tuple
((dtm(0), msisdn, callType, recTypeId, provChgAmt), (convDur))
}
```

I keep getting error:

> error: object Tuple27 is not a member of package scala.

I am not sure what the error is. Can someone help?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Scala only supports tuples with up to 22 fields. Additionally, your `frows: RDD[Array[String]]` contains `Array[String]` as elements. Thus, also your `tuple` variable in the map function is of type `Array[String]`. Therefore, it is not possible to unapply the variable `tuple` into a tuple.

But what you can do is accessing the elements of the array directly via indices.

```scala
val recKey = tuple(0)
val timestamp = tuple(4)
...
```